# Список запущенных приложений с помощью NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Используя NodeJS, я хочу получить список открытых приложений в Windows.

Вот например я взял другой код:

```
exec('tasklist', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    var lines = stdout.trim().split("\n"); //split by line
    var processes = lines.slice(2); //remove the table headers
    var parsed = processes.map(function(process) {
        return process.match(/(.+?)[\s]+?(\d+)/); //match the process name and ID
    });
    var filtered = parsed.filter(function(process) {
        return /^ll_/.test(process[1]); //filter out process names starting with ll_
    });
    console.log(filtered);
});
```

Вывод: [] пустой массив

Как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Используя NodeJS, я хочу получить список открытых приложений в Windows.

Немного изменил твой вариант...

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("tasklist", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    stdout = stdout.split('\n').map(s => s.split(/\s+/))
    stdout.splice(0, 4)
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо но только показывает имя, а есть еще данные?

Comment: Думал тебе такое и нужно... Т.е. тебе просто нужны все строки?

Comment: Ну да, нужен ppid

Comment: Сделал двумерный массив - можешь брать из него данные.

Comment: Спасибо большое!